# 'operator<' error while creating an std::pair<A,B>

Tags: c++, qt, stl

I already have a workaround for this but would still like to understand the problem.

I have a Multimap

```
multimap<QPoint,Figure*> mymap;
```

**QPoint** is a class from Qt 5.4. **Figure*** is a pointer to a
class I have concocted myself.

Now I want to add elements to that map.

This sample works fine:

```
multimap<int,int> test;
test.insert(pair<int,int>(41,43));
```

As does this one (being said workaround)

```
std::pair<QPoint,Figure*> p;
p.first = pos;
p.second =  sub_fig;
mymap.insert(p);
```

However, the plain first reflex of

```
std::pair<QPoint,Figure*> p(pos, sub_fig);
```

has the compiler at that line state something like:

```
[..]
scanner.cpp:264:17:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_function.h:371:20: error: no match for
‘operator<’ (operand types are ‘const QPoint’ and ‘const QPoint’)
  { return __x < __y; }
[..]
```

followed by the usual five kilometers of stacked STL error messages.
First: The 'types' are *not* QPoint and QPoint. They are, as
stated above, QPoint and Figure*.

Anyone who can riddle this?

## CORRECTION

My work-around does not work either after all. I had forgotten to
de-comment
    res.insert(p);

Here is the complete pertinent code:

```
multimap<QPoint,Figure*> res;
// ...
vector<Figure*> stack = figure->get_above_figure_stack();
  for (vector<Figure*>::const_iterator CI2=stack.begin();
    CI2!=stack.end();CI2++)
  {
    // ..
    Figure* sub_fig = *CI2;
    std::pair<QPoint,Figure*> p;
    p.first = pos;
    p.second =  sub_fig;
    res.insert(p); // <- The bad line.
  }
```

Comment: @Markus-Hermann The error message is clear enough: class QPoint does not have operator <. So it is not clear what you are asking about.

Comment: (operand types are ‘const QPoint’ and ‘const QPoint’): to use multimap where elements are automatically sorted, either QPoint needs to have the operator < overloaded or a predicate should be used in the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`multimap` needs an ordering relation for the keys, and its default is to use `<` (in the guise of `std::less`).

Since `QPoint` doesn't have an overload of `operator<`, the compiler is complaining that it doesn't exist.

It's not difficult to provide one:

```
bool operator< (const QPoint& lhs, const QPoint& rhs)
{
    return lhs.x() < rhs.x() || (lhs.x() == rhs.x() && lhs.y() < rhs.y());
}
```

or

```
bool lessQPoints (const QPoint& lhs, const QPoint& rhs)
{
    return lhs.x() < rhs.x() || (lhs.x() == rhs.x() && lhs.y() < rhs.y());
}

multimap<QPoint, Figure*, lessQPoints> mymap;
```

Comment: Thanks. I will accept your more detailed answer. However, I believe I will simply opt for a simple struct { QPoint, Figure* } and have a vector of these...

Answer (score 2):

The keys in a [`multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) are ordered by default with [`std::less`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) which invokes `operator<` on the key type.

Your key object (QPoint) has no `operator<` to do the comparison.

You will need to provide your own comparison function using the approprate multimap constructor.

Comment: or provide an `operator<` for the `QPoint`. However ordering points will be tricky.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Come to think of it I believe this is true. Will follow the thought and accept it for now. I do not even need an ordering. Just a map allowing for multiple copies of the same key.